# How does youtube get the params that you pass into the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Say I have this as an embed code (random youtube video...):

```
<iframe
width="560" 
height="315"
src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U5X4N2exOsU"
frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen>

</iframe>
```

How does youtube know to allow full screen (get the parameters)?

I assume it is something to do with the mess of javascript that is squished down and included inside the iframe ( http://s.ytimg.com/yt/jsbin/www-embed_core_module-vflyEJLff.js )

Comment: `U5X4N2exOsU` probably has all those settings serialized into it.

Comment: Nope, that is the embed code for this video `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5X4N2exOsU`

Comment: Isn't the default format with embed in the URL to show it fullscreen? U5X4N2exOsU is just the ID of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Expando properties on the `IFRAME` are accessible via the `window.frameElement` property.  Here's an example:

**Test1.htm:**

```
<html><body>
<iframe
width="560" 
height="315"
src="Test2.htm"
frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen=123>
</iframe>
</body></html>
```

**Test2.htm:**

```
<html><body>
<script>
document.write(window.allowfullscreen);
</script>
</body></html>
```

If the expando doesn't have a value (such as in your example), it will just be `""`.

Comment: Turns out that was the word I was looking for... but this doesn't appear to work in separate domains

Comment: @SeanJA - In that case, I'm not sure how it works - I'd have to debug into their script..

Comment: Turns out it was just `window.allowfullscreen` rather than `window.frameElement.allowfullscreen`

Comment: Actually, I couldn't get that to work, but in research I found that `window.name` is available to the iframe without any hackery.

Comment: Works in the same domain, but not separate domains... have to unaccept it